# Class Comment not found Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, autoloader

Im trying to add a comment system to my laravel app.
But I can't seem to get it working.
I have two models

```
class Post extends \Eloquent {

protected $table = 'posts';

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment','postId');
}
}
```

and my Comment model

```
class Comment extends \Eloquent {

protected $table = 'comments';

public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Post');
}

}
```

in my DashBoardController I'm trying to get the output from the models

```
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Comment;
use Input, Redirect, Sentry, Str, View, Notification;

class DashboardController extends \BaseController {
public function index()
{
    $post = Post::find(3)->comments()->comment;
    print_r($post);die;
}  
}
```

I think my database is properly linked, but now I'm getting the error
'Class Comment not found'.
Any advice on this one?

Comment: Your `Post` class is not aware of the `Comment` class. I believe you need a `use App\Models\Comment` statement in the Post model.

Comment: Make sure you do a `composer dump-autoload` and `Comment` is in your `models` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try this: composer dump-auto (as commented by user1669496)

if this didn't helped then change your model...

Change this:

```
    return $this->belongsTo('Post');
```

to smth like this:

```
    $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Post');
```

Do the similar for Post model.

Just change App\Models\XXXX to your namespace where you have Post model saved.

I had similar problem and this helped me, hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, this got it working for me.
I also needed to change my query to
    $comments = $garden->comments()->first()->comment;
to get some output!